# How to prove that $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A) + P(B)$ using $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability, inequality

I need to prove that $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A) + P(B)$ using $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

So far I have:
\begin{align*}
P(A \cup B) & = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)\\
P(A \cup B) - P(A) - P(B) & = - P(A \cap B)\\
-(P(A \cup B) - P(A) - P(B)) & = P(A \cap B)\\
-P(A \cup B) + P(A) + P(B) & = P(A \cap B)\\
P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) & = P(A \cap B)
\end{align*}

Is this correct so far? How do I finish the proof from here? Namely, where does the $\leq$ come from?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A\cup B)\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is fine. To finish just note that $P(A)+P(B)-x \leq P(A)+P(B)$ for all $x \geq 0$. take $x=P(A \cup B)$.